# "hlt"-instruction ignored/skipped in my x86_64 boot code (when I test it in QEMU)

Tags: x86, qemu, osdev

I'm writing a binary that runs in an early phase of the boot process. To be specific, a multiboot2-compliant kernel, that runs in 64-bit (AMD64/x86_64) mode after GRUBs handoff (GRUB is my bootloader). To debug and test my code, I thought of writing values to registers and execute a `hlt`. Afterwards, I can view the register values in QEMU. Surprisingly, my `hlt`-instructions are ignored/skipped and register values like in `eax` are not what I expect them to be. I don't understand why, because when I use a multiboot2-header that instructs GRUB to do a 32-bit multiboot2 handoff, it works. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project I figured out, that when GRUB does a handoff to the binary in the *EFI amd64 machine with boot services enabled*-state [[section 3.5 of Multiboot2 spec]](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot2/multiboot.html), **interrupts are enabled**. I don't know what specific interrupt QEMU reports to the CPU in this case, but if you disable them by adding a `cli` instruction once before the `hlt`, it works as desired. Don't forget to enable interrupts again, when it's the right time for it in your kernel.

Comment: Or just put `hlt` in a loop, so you can "end" your bootloader but ctrl+alt+delete on the (guest) keyboard still works to reboot.  (Not a big deal in an emulator when it's easier to end the virtual machine or click its reset button, but if you wanted to make an EFI application or toy bootloader to test on a real machine, it's a better habit.)  Although I guess it's possible that with a loop, examining registers could happen while the guest was handling a timer interrupt.